# How to reject all HTTP connections until a Tomcat webapp is fully started

Tags: tomcat, startup, httpconnection

I want Tomcat to reject (and close) all HTTP connections, while apps are not started up completely. By default Tomcat make connections wait during an app startup.

Comment: Why can't you just send a 500 or 404 from a listener in your web application if it is not fully initialized?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution works. `bindOnInit` works as well without a line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindOnInit` parameter on the connector might help (setting the value to `false`). See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html for more details.